# Parsing JSON Data/Converting to Objects

Tags: jquery

I am using the following function as a test case for my application:

```
$(function() {
var json = {
    "people": {
        "person": [{
            "name": "Peter",
            "age": 43,
            "sex": "male"},
        {
            "name": "Zara",
            "age": 65,
            "sex": "female"}]
    }
};
$.each(json.people.person, function(i, v) {
    if (v.name == "Peter") {
        alert(v.age);
        return;
    }
});
});
```

This simply searches a set of JSON data for a static input, which in this case is the name "Peter", and returns his 'age'. I want to modify this function to pull input from a text field and use it in place of the static string "Peter" so I can search for any name Id like. The function will be called from a submit button.

That is my first obstacle.

My second is Id like to use the subset of the result as an object, rather than a string, in my application. In other words, if I placed a name in a text field the function would find the name within the JSON data and return, in this case, 'age' as an object that I can then use for other calculations in the work flow.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made a fiddle that makes what you need http://jsfiddle.net/KmYJw/1/

lets say you have 2 form fields . 1 text & 1 submit

```
<input name="name" value="" type="text" />
<input value="search in json" type="submit" />
```

when you click submit . you need to take the value from the text input and search for in in the json

```
    var age; // global var

    $("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
        var searchName = $("input[name='name']").val(); // take value of text input 

        $.each(json.people.person, function(i, v) {
            if (v.name == searchName) {
                age = v.age; // attach search age to global var
                return;
            }
        });
        return;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks so much for laying this out. ?so, in this esample, I should be able to now use 'age' in calculations just as I would any other varibale that was previously defined, correct?

Comment: Thats perfect; thanks! Would it possible to have the results of the search displayed in a list? For example: If the text field searched for a specific zip code and the results returned 10 business names instead of just one? Users would then need to select a specific business name and have all of the related items returned as object.Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The main thing Im asking is what if there were more than one result returned from the search box? For example: if I entered 'Peter' in the text field and there were multiple people named 'Peter' in the JSON file, but of differing ages, how could I separate the different objects?

Answer (score 1):

If your input field is called `name` you can use the following:

```
var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
$.each(json.people.person, function(i, v){
if(v.name == name){
...
```

As for your second requirement, you can just return the `v` variable instead of returning nothing and alerting the result.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So would the second second look like such:

Comment: Sorry I'm not seeing anything. Can you post again?